# How to force a unique relationship if a property changes?

Tags: neo4j

I'm building an app using `neo4j` and I have problems when a user follows another user. Here is the query:

```
MATCH (me:User { id: 1234}),(friend:User)
WHERE friend.id = 5678
CREATE UNIQUE (me)-[r:FOLLOWS {since:1439485400}]->(friend)
RETURN r
```

The problem appears if a user repeats the process because `since` value will change and `CREATE UNIQUE` won't work.

How can I force a unique `FOLLOWS` relationship if a property changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `MERGE` for this:

```
MATCH (me:User { id: 1234}),(friend:User)
WHERE friend.id = 5678
MERGE (me)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(friend)
ON CREATE SET r.since = 1439485400
ON MATCH SET r.since = 1439485400
RETURN r
```

This guarantees only one FOLLOWS between the two users. The `since` property is updated upon subsequent invocations.

Comment: Thanks, I had to delete de `ON MATCH` line, otherwise following the same user would update the `since` value.

Comment: I thought that was the requirement :-) glad you've solved it.